# How should I display the record and hide the security constraint message in servicenow

Tags: servicenow

Lets imagine first page of a table where 60 rows gets hidden by the ACL so the page shows 40 rows and a message at the end stating : "number of rows removed by security constraints: 60"

the other page shows 40 rows and the similar message...

So I want the page should display 100 rows which are accessible for the User so that the info message "number of rows removed by security constraints" is not visible at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say Query Business Rules are exactly what you want in this case (if you want to restrict entire records). They do not show the message at the bottom, don't make you go through 100 of pages to find the 10 records you need, and are generally faster than ACLs (a Query BR only gets evaluated once whereas an ACL has to be evaluated for every record).

If your "u_requested_for" field is a reference to user, the code you need is something like:

```
if(!gs.hasRole('admin') && gs.isInteractive()){
var q = current.addQuery('u_requested_for', gs.getUserID());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only ways I know to do this, is to also write Query Business Rules.  Generally the effort isn't worth it.

Comment: I am trying this query                                                                                                                       if (!gs.hasRole("admin")) {current.addEncodedQuery("GOTOu_requested_for.nameLIKEBeth Anglin");}                             But it is only valid for Beth Anglin. I want to use the script and show only those records who haved logged in. E.g: If a user has requestedd for Beth Anglin then when User with Beth Anglin login name will be only to see the record.